# Add a parameter into a conf file through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a conf file as shown below

```
{
  "files": [
    {
 "paths": ["/srv/log/*"],
      "fields": { "type": "appLog", "app": "my_app", "env": "integration", "server": "" }
    },

    {
"paths": ["/srv/log/tomcat7/*"],
     "fields": { "type": "tomcat", "app": "my_app", "env": "integration", "server": "" }
    },

    {
"paths": ["/srv/log/nginx/*"],
     "fields": { "type": "nginxLog", "app": "my_app", "env": "integration", "server": "" }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to define the server explicitly through a shell script which is stored in a variable. Which means that i need to add the server in the "" after "server" to another script, For example: $host = my_machine.test.net , say this server address needs to be added into the conf file through my shell script . So when i run my script the above conf becomes

```
{
      "files": [
        {
     "paths": ["/srv/log/*"],
          "fields": { "type": "appLog", "app": "my_app", "env": "integration", "server": "my_machine.test.net" }
        },

        {
    "paths": ["/srv/log/tomcat7/*"],
         "fields": { "type": "tomcat", "app": "my_app", "env": "integration", "server": "my_machine.test.net" }
        },

        {
    "paths": ["/srv/log/nginx/*"],
         "fields": { "type": "nginxLog", "app": "my_app", "env": "integration", "server": "my_machine.test.net" }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I tried using "sed -i" but couldn't make it work. Can someone help.

Comment: That looks a lot like JSON. Use something like `jq`.

Answer (score 4):

The config file is a json document. Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to modify it:

```
jq --arg server 'my.server.net' '.files[].fields.server=$server' conf.json
```

---

To change the file in place:

```
mv conf.json conf.backup.json
jq --arg server 'my.server.net' '.files[].fields.server=$server' conf.json > new
mv new conf.json
```

Comment: Just a minor suggestion; keep a backup of `conf.json` instead of overwriting it immediately: `mv conf.json conf.json~ && mv new conf.json`, or just `mv -b new conf.json` where supported.

Comment: Created a backup. Who knows.

Answer (score -3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/""/"my_machine.test.net"/' file
```

Or bash script:

`$ cat script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "s/\"\"/\"$1\"/g" file
```

How to use:

```
$ ./script.sh my_machine.test.net
```